# jQuery function loading before content - breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that when the user has scrolled X pixels a `div` is set to `display:block;`

My function works fine on my local build but the site i'm implementing it on loads the page content dynamically meaning my function can't calculate the difference from X to top of the window, and doesn't work as it should.

I know I could wrap my scroll function up and call it after the page content has loaded but that's not possible - can you think of any other possible way I could do this?

```
if( $('.product-actions').length > 0 ){
    var buyBtn = $('.product-actions').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > buyBtn) {
            $('#fixed-cta').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#fixed-cta').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: everytime you go an fetch the content it means you have a function that does that. make the function throw an event/trigger a callback

Comment: I know I could do this @Saar but I mentioned above this is not possible for me - I would like to find another solution

Comment: that's not what you said you can't do above.. anyways if that is not an option then you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver